# Workflow from development to testing and merge

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, jira, workflow

I am trying to formalize the development workflow and here's the first draft. Welcome suggestions on the process and any tweaks for optimization. I am pretty new when it comes to setting up the processes and would be great to have feedback on it. P.S: We are working on an AWS Serverless application.

Create an issue link in JIRA - is tested by. The link 'is tested by' has no relevance apart from correcting displaying the relation while viewing the story.

Create a new issue type in JIRA - Testcase. This issue type should have some custom fields to fully describe the test case.

For every user story, there will be a set of test cases that are linked to the user story using the Jira linking function. The test cases will be defined by the QA.

The integration/e2e test cases will be written in the same branch as the developer. E2E test cases will be written in a separate branch as it's a separate repository (Open for discussion).

The Test case issue type should also be associated with a workflow that moves from states New => Under Testing => Success/Failure

Additionally, we could consider adding capability in the CI system to automatically move the Test case to Success when the test case passes in the CI. (This should be possible by using JIRA API ).  This is completely optional and we will most probably be doing it manually.

When all the Test cases related to a user story to success, The user story can then be moved to Done.

**A few  points to note:**

We will also be using https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1222843/aio-tests-test-management-for-jira  for test management and linking.

The QA should be working on the feature branch from day 1 for adding the test cases. Working in the same branch will enable the QA and developer to be always in Sync.  This should ensure that the developer is not blocked waiting for the test cases to be completed for the branch to be merged into development.

The feature branch will be reviewed when the pull request is created by the developer. This is to ensure that the review is not pending until the test cases have been developed/passed. This should help with quick feedback.

The focus here is on the "feature-oriented QA" process to ensure the develop branch is always release-ready and that only well-tested code is merged into the develop branch.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

- For your final status consider using Closed rather than Success/Failure. Success/Failures are outcomes rather than states. You may have other outcomes like cancelled or duplicate. You can use the Resolved field for the outcomes. You could also create a custom field for Success/Failure and decouple it from both the outcome and status. You ideally do not want your issue jumping back in forth in your workflow. If Failure is a status then you set yourself up for a lot of back and forth
- You may also want to consider a status after New Test Creation for the writing of the test case and a status after that such as Ready for Testing. This would allow you to more specifically where the work is in the flow and also capture the amount of time that is spent writing tests, how long test cases wait, and how much time is spent actually executing tests and defect remediation
- Consider adding a verification rule to your Story workflow that prevents a story from being closed until all the linked test cases are closed

Answer (score 0):

[AIO Tests for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1222843/aio-tests-test-management-for-jira?tab=overview&hosting=cloud), unlike other test management systems, does not clutter Jira, by creating tests as issues.  So you need not create an issue type at all.

With it's zero setup time, you can simply start creating tests against stories. It has a workflow from Draft to Published (essentially equaling Ready for Testing).
The AIO Tests jira panel shows the cases associated with the stories and their last execution status to get a glimpse of the testing progress of the story as shown below.  It allows everyone from the Product to the Developer to get a glimpse of the testing status.

[image]

You can also create testing tasks and get a glimpse of the entire execution cycle in the AIO Tests panel.
It also has a [Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/aio-tests/) + REST APIs to make it part of your CI/CD process.